# Chaining in javascript plugin not working

Tags: javascript

Found a nice tutorial online to build you're own JS library/plugin [here](https://gomakethings.com/how-to-create-your-own-vanilla-js-dom-manipulation-library-like-jquery/).

In my example below I have added the parents method but this isn't working proper, as a noob i have tried a lot but i cant get it to work but no result.

I' am trying to chain the methods but this is not working as the parents method is stopping the chain.

Anybody any idea on what i am doing wrong?

```
var X = (function () {

    var Constructor = function (selector) {
        if (!selector) return;
        if (selector === 'document') {
            this.nodes = [document];
        } else if (selector === 'window') {
            this.nodes = [window];
        } else if(typeof selector === 'string') {
            this.nodes = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
        }else{
            this.nodes = [selector];
        }
    };

    Constructor.prototype.each = function (callback) {
        if (!callback || typeof callback !== 'function') return;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.nodes.length; i++) {
            callback(this.nodes[i], i);
        }
        return this;
    };

    Constructor.prototype.addClass = function (className) {
        this.each(function (item) {
            item.classList.add(className);
        });
        return this;
    };

    Constructor.prototype.parents = function(selector) {
        var elements   = [];
        var elem       = this.nodes[0];
        var isSelector = selector !== undefined;
        while ((elem = elem.parentElement) !== null) {
            if (elem.nodeType !== Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                continue;
            }
            if (!isSelector || elem.matches(selector)) {
                elements.push(elem);
            }
        }
        return elements;
    };

    var init = function (selector) {
        return new Constructor(selector);
    };

    return init;

})();

X('.class').addClass('works');//works
X('.class').parents('.parent').addClass('doesnotworks');//not working
```

Comment: `elements` is an array and not an instance of `Constructor`

Comment: i see, have fixed this with this.nodes = elements. Is there a better way to also fix the issue with multiple nodes as i am now only selecting the first

Comment: also dont forget to add your answer so that i can vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make a new instance when you return the parents so it can be chained. I had to also change your else statement to handle an array of nodes passed in.

```js
var X = (function () {

    var Constructor = function (selector) {
        if (!selector) return;
        if (selector === 'document') {
            this.nodes = [document];
        } else if (selector === 'window') {
            this.nodes = [window];
        } else if(typeof selector === 'string') {
            this.nodes = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
        } else {
            // Added check to allow for an array to be passed in
            this.nodes = Array.isArray ? selector : [selector];
        }
    };

    Constructor.prototype.each = function (callback) {
        if (!callback || typeof callback !== 'function') return;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.nodes.length; i++) {
            callback(this.nodes[i], i);
        }
        return this;
    };

    Constructor.prototype.addClass = function (className) {
        this.each(function (item) {
            item.classList.add(className);
        });
        return this;
    };

    Constructor.prototype.parents = function(selector) {
        var elements   = [];
        var elem       = this.nodes[0];
        var isSelector = selector !== undefined;
        while ((elem = elem.parentElement) !== null) {
            if (elem.nodeType !== Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                continue;
            }
            if (!isSelector || elem.matches(selector)) {
                elements.push(elem);
            }
        }
        // create a new instance of your constructor with the new elements
        return new Constructor(elements);
    };

    var init = function (selector) {
        return new Constructor(selector);
    };

    return init;

})();

X('.class').addClass('works');//works
X('.class').parents('.parent').addClass('doesnotworks');//not working
```

```css
.parent { border: 1px solid red; padding: 5px; }
.class { border: 1px solid purple; padding: 5px; }


.works {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.doesnotworks {
  outline: 3px dashed green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="class">foo</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good answer, but I have two points of criticism. 1) Why are you using the ternary operator when all other checks are `else if` statements? I suggest doing this check in a separate `else if` condition. 2) Why specifically test for an array? What if a `NodeList` is passed? I would change the check to an iterable check. eg. `else if (selector[Symbol.iterator]) { this.nodes = Array.from(selector); }` This allows the user to pass in more than only arrays.

Comment: "*Why*?" Because I spent 2 minutes making it work.... There are a bunch of things I would change, but not a code review.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that `elements` is an array, not an instance of `Constructor`.

Fix it using this:

```
this.nodes = elements
```